# OpenAI API error when using a fine-tuned model: "The model `xxxxx` does not exist"

Tags: javascript, axios, openai-api, fine-tuning

I'm trying to do a chatbot with a fine tuned model.

I'm doing my request like this:

```js
    const API_KEY = "/";
    const ORG_ID = "/";
    const headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: "Bearer " + API_KEY,
      "OpenAI-Organization": ORG_ID,
    };
    const res = await axios.post(
      "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions",
      {
        model: "ft-modelname",
        messages: [
          {
            role: "system",
            content: "your name is Name.",
          },
          {
            role: "user",
            content: message,
          },
        ],
      },
      { headers }
    );
```

And after listing my models with the API I can see it, it does exist.

But I have this error in the console:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "The model `ft-modelname` does not exist",
        "type": "invalid_request_error",
        "param": null,
        "code": null
    }
}
```

After looking up, i can't find a way to do this, some people use open ai engine api instead of completion, but it don't work too.
Do you have any ideas ?

Thank you.

Edit:
It works when I'm not using a fine tune model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE: 22 August 2023**

Fine-tuning for GPT-3.5 is now available, as stated in the official [OpenAI blog](https://openai.com/blog/gpt-3-5-turbo-fine-tuning-and-api-updates):

> Fine-tuning for GPT-3.5 Turbo is now available, with fine-tuning for
> GPT-4 coming this fall.

Consequently, the [Chat Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/chat-completions-api) (i.e., the GPT-3.5 API) endpoint *can* be used for a fine-tuned model, but only for a GPT-3.5 fine-tuned model. For a GPT-3 fine-tuned model, use the [Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/completions-api) (i.e., the GPT-3 API) endpoint.

As stated in the official OpenAI documentation:

> When a job has succeeded, you will see the `fine_tuned_model` field
> populated with the name of the model when you retrieve the job
> details. You may now specify this model as a parameter to in the [Chat
> Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/chat-completions-api) (for `gpt-3.5-turbo`) or legacy [Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/completions-api) (for
> `babbage-002` and `davinci-002`), and make requests to it using the
> [Playground](https://platform.openai.com/playground).

---

#### Problem

You're using the wrong API endpoint.

#### Solution

**Use the [Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/completions-api) (i.e., the GPT-3 API) endpoint instead of the [Chat Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/chat-completions-api) (i.e., the GPT-3.5 API) endpoint.**

As stated in the official [OpenAI documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning/use-a-fine-tuned-model):

> When a job has succeeded, the `fine_tuned_model` field will be populated
> with the name of the model. You may now specify this model as a
> parameter to our [Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions/create), and make requests to it using the
> [Playground](https://platform.openai.com/playground).

#### In general

**Python**

```
import os
import openai

openai.api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")

openai.Completion.create(
    model = FINE_TUNED_MODEL,
    prompt = YOUR_PROMPT)
```

**NodeJS**

```
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");

const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});

const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

const response = await openai.createCompletion({
  model: FINE_TUNED_MODEL
  prompt: YOUR_PROMPT,
});
```

**cURL**

```
curl https://api.openai.com/v1/completions \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $OPENAI_API_KEY" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"prompt": YOUR_PROMPT, "model": FINE_TUNED_MODEL}'
```

**OpenAI CLI**

```
openai api completions.create -m <FINE_TUNED_MODEL> -p <YOUR_PROMPT>
```

#### Your case

Try this:

```
const res = await axios.post(
  "https://api.openai.com/v1/completions", {
    model: "ft-modelname",
    prompt: "Say this is a test",
  }, {
    headers
  }
);
```